# How to change the text position

Tags: vertical-alignment, drop-cap

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
 \usepackage{yfonts}[1998/10/03]

  \begin{document}

 \frakfamily\Large\fraklines
 \textcolor{Green}{\yinipar{E}\textswab{text} \\}
 \end{document}
```

I am attaching an image along with this post, I am able to achieve the first image, however I am looking to achieve the second.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use `\textinit`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{yfonts}[1998/10/03] 
\begin{document}
\frakfamily\Large\fraklines
\textcolor{Green}{\textinit{E}\textswab{text} \\}
\end{document}
```

[image: textinit example]

Answer (score 8):

A second the use of `lettrine`. If you don't want to have the initial hang into the margin (as in Gonzalo's answer) you can use

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{yfonts}[1998/10/03]
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for testing

\renewcommand\LettrineFont{\initfamily\color{Green}\tiny}

\begin{document}
\swabfamily\Large\fraklines
\lettrine[lines=1]{S}{ome} text
\lipsum*
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

This also shows one nicety of `lettrine`: you can easily define a global font for it by changing `\LettrineFont` appropriately. In this case, I change it to the initials font family from `yfonts` and select the color and size. The `[lines=1]` argument to `\lettrine` sets the layout so that only one line of text is indented with the initial (which gives the layout that you want). You can set this globally (so that you don't have to pass the argument every time) with `\setcounter{DefaultLines}{1}`.

Side note: You should use `xcolor` instead of `color`. And your `\frakfamily` is immediately overridden by `\textswab`. So I simply changed it to `\swabfamily`.

Answer (score 3):

The `lettrine` package could be an option:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{yfonts}[1998/10/03]
\usepackage{lettrine}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\frakfamily\Large\fraklines
\frakfamily\Large\fraklines

\textcolor{Green}{\lettrine[lraise=2.5,loversize=-0.55]{\yinipar{E}}{\textswab{text}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]